# Change android fragment size inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

I'm developing an app with tabs following these tutorials:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html
my layout xml is like this:
`<main LinearLayout>`

`<viewPager/>  <-- contains fragments`

`<common LinearLayout/>`

`<common ListView/>`

`</main LinearLayout>`

When user swipes between tabs, the app switches between three different fragments but the common sections does not change across swipes. The problem is that the new fragment does not have the right size (usually is too small that i cannot see some form widgets). How can I resize the area taken by a fragment when the new fragment is shown?

Comment: You mean the size of the layout that the fragment used in the `ViewPager` Tabs ?

Comment: Yes, sometimes the viewpager is too small to contain the fragment. It's useless to set weights for viewpager, linearlayout and listview. I should force redraw of the whole activity or i should resize the viewpager.